# Nullpointer in ActivityThread.java:2524

Tags: android

I am getting a crash from my crash reporting tool which I don't know how to solve. The stack trace is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleWindowVisibility(ActivityThread.java:2524)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:963)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't have the logs and I can't reproduce it. It seems to be happening when the user returns to the app. It has happend on different phones running 2.3.6 and 2.3.7.

Anyone who knows how to solve this?

Comment: You are missing the caused by, see the line that is indicated there.

Comment: @user1597833 There is no "caused by". This is the whole stacktrace, nullpointer in ActivityThread.java:2524.

Comment: 11-14 10:55:34.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-14 10:55:34.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 10:55:34.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1354): Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
11-14 10:55:34.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1354):  at com.test.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:54)

Comment: can you show some of your code?

Comment: @user1597833 I know what a "caused by" clause is, but it's not present for all crashes. For example look at crashes for "Out of memory" or "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState".

Comment: @NAYOSO I have 50+ activities/fragments and there is no reference to my code in the crash. I don't see which code I should post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be custom ROMs as the source code of 2.3.6 & 2.3.7 `ActivityThread.java:2524` is inside `deliverResults()` not `handleWindowVisibility()`. Check the source code of [android.app.ActivityThread](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/app/ActivityThread.java?av=f#2524). My advise is that if the rate of these crashes is not huge, you can ignore them as you need to know the exact ROM to be able to know the reason for crashing and it will be very difficult. If you want to take a wild guess, then check what you are doing in your activity that may cause NullPointerException in `handleWindowVisibility`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the source code and came to about the same conclusion. However, the crash has happend twice today for one user in a small user base (<10 users) which got me worried.

Comment: I think you can safely ignore that. If you have tested your code on 2.3.6 & 2.3.7 without problems and the issue is not frequent nor widely spread, then don't worry.